# Lines with Circular Terminators and Symbols with Overlines

Tags: shift-register, diagram, 74hc595

I'm a newbie to breadboards and Arduinos. I'm playing around with the 74HC595 shift register in order to power a basic segment display to show some numbers. I was looking at the data sheet for the 74HC595 and was curious about the conventions used in the functional diagram. I've included a screenshot of this diagram for your convenience. In particular, I notice that the `MR` and `OE` lines both terminate in a circle and have overlines in their symbols while the other lines do not.

What does this mean? What's the convention here? In the "PINNING" section of the data sheet, I see that these lines are active LOW. Is that the meaning of the circle and the overline? Or does it mean something else? Thank you in advance.

[image: Functional Diagram of the 74HC595][image: Pinout of the 74HC595]

Comment: `I see that these lines are active LOW. Is that the meaning of the circle and the overline?` yes.

Comment: MR- master reset , active low. OE- output enable, active low. Everything written in the table. Small round and line above means zerro active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  \$\overline {\mathrm{OE}}\$, *OE, nOE, !OE, and probably others mean "not OE", or "OE, active-low".

The bubble on a logic input means that the sense of the input is inverted -- so in the data sheet you're looking at, \$\overline {\mathrm{OE}}\$ is entirely consistent with the bubble.

Note that it's pretty common practice to have control signals be active low.  This originally came about because TTL logic could pull a line down with a lot more authority than it could pull it up, and because it was not uncommon to have more than one controlling device pull a line low, with resistors used to pull the line high (Google on "wired-or" and "open-collector").  It's carried forward mostly by tradition, although you still see parts that have more current sinking ability than current sourcing ability.